# CSS, Inline-block display inside <anchor> tags

Tags: html, css

I added an anchor symbol right in front of every anchor in my document

```css
a::after {
    content: "\2693";
}
```

```html
<a href="somewhere...">i am an anchor</a>
```

Now I don't want to include the pseudo element in the underlined text, so from digging around a little I learned that I cannot achieve this with `text-decoration` but somehow using `display: inline-block;` solves the problem

```css
a::after {
    content: "\2693";
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="somewhere...">i am an anchor</a>
```

Can anyone explain these results ?
I've been reading about `inline-block` display, but couldn't understand why it works in this case ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline-block elements doesn't inherit text-underline from their parent. Test below code and you will understand:

```
<div style="color:red;text-decoration:underline">
  Div with underlined text
  <span style="display:inline-block;text-decoration:inherit;">Inline block span</span>
</div>
```

Remove the **"text-decoration:inherit"** from the span and underline is gone. So in order to get text-underline for child inline-block elements, you need to inherit it from parent.

**EDIT:**
That's how it is. Text-decoration is not propagated to child elements in certain cases. Refer official W3C documentation : [W3C Doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props)

> Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: This doesn't explain why inline children appear to "inherit" the parent text-decoration even though inherit isn't specified for them either.

Comment: And also why `text-decoration: none` doesn't seem to remove it either?

Comment: That's how it is. I have edited my answer. Refer W3C doc.